# How to formulate my resume, if a PhD defense exam fails with mark “Dissertation passed, Oral failed”

Tags: phd, thesis

My PhD examination consists of two parts namely the dissertation note and the oral note. Unfortunately, it was fails with “Dissertation passed, Oral failed”.
What could be the best way to form it in my resume? 
Could I write: finished PhD study only with Dissertation, in short “PhD Dissertation”?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this means more precisely? In the systems I am familiar with it is practically impossible to have an approved dissertation and fail the oral defense unless it turns out you did not actually understand your own dissertation.

Comment: Resume aside, the obvious advice is to take the oral again and complete your PhD in all senses.  The idea that an academic department would pass someone on their dissertation but *definitively and permanently* disallow them from completing their PhD is awfully baffling to me.  Could that actually be your situation?!? (I hope not.)

Answer (score 16):

So, have you officially been granted a degree of Ph.D. or have you not?
I cannot tell from the way that your question is currently phrased.

If you have a Ph.D., you can simply honestly write down that you have a Ph.D. degree, and not attempt to explain whatever it means at your institution to be given a Ph.D. while failing your defense.  Don't hide it if you are asked, but if this is the case then apparently your institution thinks that you are worthy of a Ph.D., and it's up to others to judge whether they respect your institution.

If you do not actually have a Ph.D. yet, then you can't write that you have a Ph.D., and it probably doesn't matter all that much to the reader that you have an accepted dissertation.